# has_many through with dynamic condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to build an association like this:

```
has_many :foos, through: self.attr == 'bar' ? :association1 : :association2
```

but I got a trouble that I can not access `self.attr` here. So what can I do?

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

May be do it as 2 associations:

```
has_many :association1_foos, through: :association1
has_many :association2_foos, through: :association2

def foos
  self.attr == 'bar' ? self.association1_foos : self.association2_foos
end
```